# How much threads can be created and executed on single cpu core?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a program with multithreading and 1 dual-core cpu on working machine, how much threads can I create parallel for these 2 cores? In some articles I saw that cpu cor can handle only on thread. Does it mean that I can create only 2 threads? Or I can create multiple threads, but only 2 of them will be executed by core in a tact? I know, that this question is simple, but, I'm confused a little bit

Comment: You can create lots of threads. It's just if there are more threads than cpus then the extra threads will have to wait for a running thread to get swapped out before they get to run.

Comment: @NathanHughes lots of threads on cpus, but what about cpus cores?

Comment: Modern hardware and OS combinations can easily handle thousands of them.

Comment: Modern cpu cores often have multithreading, i.e. they can physically execute two separate threads at the same time. Logically you can start any number of threads and they'll simply seem to run slower and slower, but still mostly look like they are running all at the same time (the beauty of preemptive multithreading). For CPU-heavy stuff you want slightly more threads than your CPU(s) can physically run, but not much more.

Comment: @rzwitserloot "modern hardware" is abstract category. I'm trying to understand situation around concrete thing - cpu cores

Comment: Unless it's something that is intentionally incredibly underspecced relative to normal expectations (example: A raspberry pi, a machine that was built 15 years ago, a TV set-top box, that sort of thing. Non-examples: Phones, tablets, cheap laptops - unless they are 10 years+ old, they're modern), thousands is fine. If you have specific hardware in mind, write a test instead of asking. Let me put it differently, what are you expecting? Someone to post a table of 5000 different devices and an exact number as to how many threads you can run? That's.. obviously preposterous.

Comment: @rzwitserloot nope, I dont need tests and benchmarks, just want to understand - cpu core executes 1 thread in time of its cycle or multiple threads

Comment: 1 thread at a time, hopping around when the thread it executes no longer needs CPU (due to waiting for something, say, disk or network), or when it's been running for a while. Each core is doing that, on most architectures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern hardware and OS combinations can easily handle thousands of them. And they can all be in the 'running state'.

However, let's say you have 2000 threads, 2 CPUs in the box, and each CPU has 16 cores, then certainly at most 32 of your running threads are truly 'executing stuff' - the other ones are ready to go if any of he 32 currently actually executing threads do something that isn't CPU-dependent (for example, waiting for some bytes to flow in from the network, or bytes to be read from a disk), or just time passes (eventually the CPU+OS+JVM work together to pre-empt an executing thread - to pause it so that it doesn't hog the resources).

The bottleneck you're most likely to run into first is memory: Each thread needs a stack, and stacks take memory. If for example you are working with 1MB stacks, creating 2000 threads means you now have 2GB worth of stackspace alone, and the java heap (Where all objects live) probably also takes a GB or 2, that's 4. On your average provisioned IAAS box you don't have that much.

A simple solution to that problem is that you can actually control the stack size when you create a new thread object. You can use this to make much smaller stacks, for example, 64k stacks - now 2000 threads only take an eight of a GB. Of course, a 64k stack is not capable of running particularly deeply nested methods - usually if you're creating thousands of threads, the code they actually end up running should be relatively simple and not create large stacks or do recursive calling.

If you mess this up, you'll get `StackOverflowError`. Then you know to either adjust the code or increase the stack sizes.

If you're not making thousands of threads (merely, say, hundreds), don't worry about it. Just.. make em and run em, trust the OS+CPU+JVM to sort it out for you.